# How I check in PHP if a string contains or not specific things?

Tags: php, string

I need a function in php that will work in this way.

```
$string = "blabla/store/home/blahblah";

If in $string you find /store/ then do this, else do that.
```

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = "blabla/store/home/blahblah";
if (preg_match("|/store/|", $string)){
    //do this
}
else{
    //do that
}
```

or

```
$string = "blabla/store/home/blahblah";
if (false !== strpos($string, "/store")){
   //do this
}
else{
    //do that
}
```

Comment: this is discouraged by documentation. Prefer strpos() : "Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster."

Comment: In this particular example, using `strpos()` is better because it accomplishes the same thing and is faster than a regex.

Comment: `strpos` can return 0 meaning "I found it at the very beginning", but 0 is falsy and your if statement will lead to an incorrect result.

Comment: +1 for giving nice examples, but as the [PHP-doc states](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#refsect1-function.preg-match-notes): "Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster."

Answer (score 4):

you're looking for [strpos() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: `if(strpos($string, "/store/") !== false) { do_something(); }`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (strpos($string, "/store/") !== false) {
    // found
} else {
    // not found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the strrpos function

e.g.

```
$pos = strrpos($yourstring, "b");
if ($pos === true) { // note: three equal signs
//string found...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're looking for the [stristr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) function.

```
$string = "blabla/store/home/blahblah";
if(stristr($string, "/store/")) { do_something(); }
```